# Why can't typescript infer tuple return type in RxJs stream?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, types, rxjs

In composing an observable stream, returning a tuple from the map function is inferred by the compiler as a union instead of a tuple.

For example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class MyType {
  constructor(private name: string) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ''
})
export class AppComponent {
  observable$ = from([new MyType('obj1'), new MyType('obj2')]).pipe(
    map((value, index) => [value, index]),
    tap(([value, index]) => console.log(value, index))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Check it out on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t9af6p), if you hover over `value` or `index` in the function parameter in `tap`, they both get inferenced to `number | MyType` when it should understand that `value: MyType` and `index: number`.

if I annotate map by filling in the generics: `map<MyType, [MyType, number]>(...` then the typing is correct.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't typescript understand that tuple without having to explicitly pass the type?

I'm using rxjs @ 6.4.0 and typescript @ 3.8.3 locally, but stackblitz has more recent versions and still presents this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `map` function, you are returning an array, not tuple.

You can use `as const` to force the tuple type:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  observable$ = from([new MyType('obj1'), new MyType('obj2')]).pipe(
    map((value, index) => [value, index] as const),
    tap(([value, index]) => console.log(value, index))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

See [Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

> array literals with `const` assertions will be inferred with `readonly` tuple types